# Is it Possible to have Two Alternating Pistons in Blender Physics?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to do a two-slider animation using Blender Rigid Body physics.
I want each slider to go on opposite direction at any time.
I tried using Force fields but to no avail. Almost every video on youtube about Blender Physics is about Demolition.
This model is for the ailevon (aileron+elevator) mechanism for a jet aircraft I am designing.
[image: The mechanism at rest]
Currently, with the current settings, the ailevon (the Green cube on your left), is only going up, that is, in one direction. I want it to swing up AND down.
I first tried using only one slider. But it didn't work. So, I thought using two sliders would. That too is not working.
Am I missing anything.
Any idea is welcomed!

Comment: I don’t really understand the motion you are describing. Could you provide some images with it moved in each direction to make it clear which bits are moving when the pistons move?

Comment: Is it important that this is a physics simulation? Could it be a rig with drivers/constraints instead?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102990/how-can-one-rig-a-stirling-engine

Comment: outside of being an academic exercise, using physics is definitely not the best way to go about this. Look into drivers if you haven't already. Basically you're trying to **simulate** where you should be **rigging** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Robin Betts comment was probably the closest I was looking for.
However, in the meantime I have switched to  a more simple mechanism proposed by the students of Delf TU in Holland.
Here is how I rendered it.
[image: TU Delf Aileron Mechanism]

They key in making this happen is by setting the piston to Animated and building keyframes on it. The rest moves by itself through Physics.
Thanks to all!