# Rigging a piston with the piston rod as control bone

Tags: rigging

I'd like to create a simulation with a pneumatic cylinder. (See pic below)
The piston rod is fixed to a lever (Bone.002) which should rotate around the 3D Cursor when the cylinder rod (Bone)moves.
I only found tuts where the lever controls the piston but I want to make it like real, so that the piston rod controls the lever.
Maybe someone has a clue or knows a tutorial link for this?

[image: Picture]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102990/how-can-one-rig-a-stirling-engine-piston/103000

Comment: wow, that's a masterpiece! thanks for this smart advise! using a scale bone instead of moving the bone. It works fine.

Answer (score 4):

> the piston rod controls the lever.

That's doable with IK and a scaling control.  Note that Bone.001 needs to rotate as well, if the lever (Bone.002) is to maintain its current origin and not change length.

[image]

Rest pose on left.  All bones have inherit stretch set to "None".  Ik2 is locked in all but one axis.  Control the piston length by scaling "ctrl".  To meet the needs of the IK, it and ik2 will rotate as needed.